# Flask url_for - incorrect static folder path

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to add an image to my quiz.html page with Flask using:

```
<img src='{{url_for('static', filename='img/question-mark.png')}}' alt='' >
```

When I look at the page source, it's interpreted as:
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/quiz/static/img/question-mark.png` rather than:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/img/question-mark.png`

Yet, my `.css` files and `.js` files load in `quiz.html` using the same syntax just fine. How can I get the correct static file path?

My current structure is:

```
 |-app.py
 |-templates/
   |-main.html
   |-quiz.html
 |-static/
   |-css/
   |-img/
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("main.html")

@app.route('/quiz/')
def quiz():
    return render_template("quiz.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: did you import url_for from flask? Please don't mix "" and '', can you separate those?

Comment: Look at this example: **<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='ayrton_senna_movie_wallpaper_by_bashgfx-d4cm6x6.jpg')}}" />**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Jinja script to write a static image source. Just write:

```
<img src="/static/img/question-mark.png">
```

All the static resources are automatically served under `/static`.